# Specification List table laravel php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design, eloquent

I'm using laravel with eloquent and I want to create a table (php) with specification for some products, like this

```
     Models  |   ModelA   | ModelB  |
    Size     |     234    |    321  |
 Sensitivity |      21    |     -   |
 Temperature |           23         |
```

And my DB tables :

Models:

```
   idModel  |  nameModel 
       1    |   ModelA
       2    |   ModelB
```

Specs:

```
idSpec |   titleSpec |   spec |  idModel
   1   |     Size    |   234  |     1
   2   |     Size    |   321  |     2
   3   | Sensitivity |    21  |     1
   4   | Temperature |    23  |     1
   5   | Temperature |    23  |     2
```

So I want to create the table with some rules:

- I want to organize it by model and by titleSpec
- can't repeat the titleSpecs
- if ModelA has one specific titleSpec and ModelB doesn't, it gets an '-'
- if Model B and Model A has same value in the titleSpec, it gets an colspan with the value!

I'm using eloquent relationships! 
My only problem is how to build this; should I change the DB structure?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a job for the model! Your controller needs to organize and prepare the data for the view.